# Email addresses of contacts come back in an unexpected form with Contact API in Office 365 Exchange Online

Tags: c#, ms-office, odata, exchangewebservices

I was trying out the new contacts api and tried the following:

https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts?$select=DisplayName,EmailAddress1

I get something like this:

"EmailAddress1":"/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (**********)/cn=Recipients/cn=GUID-Joe.Cartano"

if I have added the contact through exchange. If I add a new contact manually I get the email address I expect. Is there a more complete reference for the contacts api, or is there a way to get actual email addresses back for these contacts?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896(v=office.15).aspx#sectionSection8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896%28v=office.15%29.aspx#sectionSection8)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Accept="odata.metadata=full" setting as explained in this thread [Return all email metadata in Office 365 Mail REST API preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270405/return-all-email-metadata-in-office-365-mail-rest-api-preview) to return what is available.